# IntelliJ auto format Ctrl+Alt+L notation problems

Tags: intellij-idea, notation, autoformatting

Maybe that's a weird question, but I have used java for years now and only recently started using the Ctrl+Alt+L on IntelliJ to auto-format my code. It works pretty great, only it has one problem, which is it changes the tabs notation to a 2-spaces notation, meaning if before I had:

```
public class Example {
    int i;
    int j;
}
```

now I have:

```
public class Example {
  int i;
  int j;
}
```

I don't know why, but it really bothers me. Is there a way to change that so when I Ctrl+Alt+L then I don't mess up the tabs notation?

Comment: Please check "Tab" and "Indent" size in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java"

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by removing the app that was causing this problem.
I removed **"Mouse Without Borders"** app and then my IntelliJ Pycharm worked without issues.
Try to find which app in your system is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set spaces indents by default, go to **Settings → Editor → Code Style → Java**, make sure the **Use tab character** checkbox is unchecked and set the **Indent** value:

[image]

you can look around a lot.

Comment: That is useful, but unfortunatly it doesnt solve my problem. My problem, is whenever I use Ctrl+Alt+L to auto format the file, all the intends become 2-spaced instead of 4-spaced.

Comment: I think you misunderstood... The default indent is 4, when I hit Enter the auto indent makes a 4 length indent which is good. the problem is when I auto format the file with Ctrl+Alt+L, all the 4 length indents become a 2 length indents. I wish there is a way to change that.

Comment: Okay..... what I know and what I tested before I posted my answer is. If you change the indent and then come back to your code. You will see indent notification on top of your files. hit `ctrl + alt +L` and it will change to mentioned indent only.

Comment: If not for you then I will say just try changing once and then set back to 4. And invalidate chache and restart

Comment: Read here too.... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html

Comment: Please ty to disable "Detect and use existing file indents" and ''Enable EditorConfig" options in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style"